# Lumia 820: video from microSD ~ minimum spec?

Tags: nokia-lumia-820, micro-sd

I've been experiencing difficulties with mp4 playback from SD cards.

Playing the same mp4 file from two different microSD cards on a Lumia 820:

- SanDisk 8GB MicroSD HC (class 2), video plays with no problems
- SanDisk 32GB Ultra MicroSD HC-I (class 10), video stutters every 30 seconds or so and is unwatchable

Is there a problem with throughput from large SD cards or do I have a a faulty card?

Comment: What class cards are they? eg Class 1, Class 10. The higher the class the faster read/write speeds. It could be too slow.